# Date sort in JS where the array of objects has the word "week" in it

Tags: javascript

[image: list of dates]

How does one begin to sort this? I could not find something similar online.
I have tried to sort by length but that made it even more of a mess like so:

```
dateButtons.sort((a,b) => {
  return b.text.length - a.text.length
})
```

where as "text" is equal to the date string

Comment: That image is virtually useless to us. Show us a sample of exactly what is is you are trying to sort. If it's an array show us a sample of the array code, if it is elements in the page then show us the relevant html. See [mre]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Hint : You need to parse the year and week out of the strings as numbers and use those values in the sort comparator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method and split year and month in the compare function:

```js
const dates = ['2020 week 2', '1999 week 32', '2021 week 20', '2020 week 4', '2020 week 1'];

console.log(dates.sort((lhs, rhs) => {
  const [lyear, lweek] = lhs.split(' week ');
  const [ryear, rweek] = rhs.split(' week ');
  return lyear - ryear || lweek - rweek;
}));
```

Comment: I believe you want `||` not `&&`

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, thank you.